# Multiple hosted Websites with only one backend

Tags: firebase, architecture, web-hosting

I want to create several similar webshops and manage everything from one centralized place.
I wouldn't program the backend myself as it would take a lot of time + I don't want to update the security regularly.
I would also not take multiple ready-made template webistes, because it would cost a lot monthly.

So far the best solution I have found would be the following:

I would code the frontend myself with HTML, CSS, JS (+ maybe VueJS) and get the backend as service from Firebase.

Quesiton Nr.1: Have you any better idea?

Quesiton Nr.2:
If this solution is ok, then: is it possible to manage multiple hosted websites with Firebase with one backend? I mean separate domain for each websites, but 1 database and generally only one backend for all webshops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can set up one or more Firebase Hosting sites in a single Firebase project. Since the sites are all in the same Firebase project, all the sites can access the other Firebase resources of the project.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites?authuser=0&hl=it#set_up_deploy_targets

Basically you add a site from the Firebase Hosting console, for example "my-app.web.app".

In the project directory use the following command:

```
firebase target:apply hosting TARGET_NAME my-app
```

The target name is only used to help you during the deployment, obviously choose it with a criterion.

The `.firebaserc` file should look like this:

```
 ...
 "targets": {
    "your-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "TARGET_NAME": [
          "my-app"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

In the `firebase.json` file you have to transform the `"hosting"` field into an array and add, in addition to the already existing target, the new one.

```
...
"hosting": [
    ...
    {
      "target": "TARGET_NAME",
      "public": "custom_dist",
      "ignore": [...],
      "rewrites": [...]
    }
  ]
...
```

At this point to deploy, just use the following command:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:TARGET_NAME
```